# Terminal across two Monitors

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, display-settings

I have two 24" Monitors connect to my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. 
For some purposes it would be helpful to maximize my Terminal over both Monitors as one big Window. 
I can drag a window larger with the mouse, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73573/how-to-maximise-a-window-across-two-monitors) could be helpful. But all windows will be maximized to both monitors, not only the terminal.

Quoting the answer from the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73573/how-to-maximise-a-window-across-two-monitors):

> This is possible by manually telling Compiz the screen output size, using the combined resolution of the two monitors. That's where the limitation kicks in: both displays need to have the same (vertical) resolution for this to make sense (else you'd end up with cut off content on the smaller screen or dead space on the bigger one).
>
> For example, with two monitors with 1920x1080 resolution, you'd:
>
> - Open the CompizConfig Settings Manager (if you haven't already, install the `compizconfig-settings-manager` package) and go to the *General Options* plugin.
> - On the *Display Settings* tab, disable the *Detect Outputs* checkbox, select the *640x480+0+0* entry and click on *Edit*,
> - Now change this to *3840x1080+0+0* and hit close.
>
> [image]
>
> Compiz should now treat your multi-monitor setup as one big output.

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for but it works. Thank you!